# Wordpress: can I launch a small javascript declared on the same page? Or how to upload .js file to Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm completly new to wordpress. I just want to use single javascript snippet on a page. For example:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
//do something
}
</script>
// a bit later
<input type="button" name="testButton" onclick="myFunction()">
```

And in developers console in Chrome I get an error: `"Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request."`

I've done some research and I think that I know it's origin - it seems that I have to add an external file with my `javascript` code. The bad thing is, that I have literally no idea how to do it, in spite of researching for the past few hours. Maybe it's very easy and I'm missing the simple solution, but I just don't know how to upload .js file. I've bumped into some topics saying that I have to use a php function, `wp_enqueue_script()`, but it still needs the .js file to be uploaded to `wordpress` server. Do I have to upload it as Media, a page, or what? And still, if I have to upload a `javascript` file each single time when I want to change something, application development will be a pain in the butt...

So is there maybe an easy way to put my `javascript` function definition in the same file where the function is used? That would be possibly the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding external Javascript files is probably the way to go. You upload them in the same way you would do if this was a regular HTML site, (ie using FTP or something similar).

Then you can reference it in the header.php file (accesible under the Appearance -> Editor in Wordpress).

Some themes allow you to add Javascript to the top/bottom of each page, you may want to check if your theme allows that. (check the manual with the theme or their support).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, unfortunately I don't have access to FTP today. Can you explain what you mean by "you can reference it in the hear.php" ? To use wp_enqueue_script() ?

Comment: Is there no where on that theme that allows you to input javascript?

Comment: I uploaded .js file on ftp and now I can use it to listen do onclick events ;)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for accepting the answer. IF you REALLY liked it you can even click the up arrow ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, still don't have reputation >= 15 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add this whole code in header.php file of your WordPress and add

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

before your code.